# SelectDateWidget - passing date range

Tags: django, widget, django-forms, date-range

I am using SelectDateWidget and want to pass in a date range based on max and min date values from my database.

```
oldest = Item.objects.all().aggregate(Min('date'))['date__min']
start_year = Item.objects.get(date=oldest).date.year  # 2012

newest = Item.objects.all().aggregate(Max('date'))['date__max']
end_year = Item.objects.get(date=newest).date.year  # 2013


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    date_range = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(start_year, end_year)))
```

The above shows the `start_year` only. This is the only choice to select.

This one below works well, and them both seem about the same to me.

```
date_range = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(2008, 2013)))
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your perception of the range function is off (the last argument of the range is not included in the list itself, its the limiter)

```
>> range(2012, 2013)
.. [2012]
```

You require an offset if you want to include 2013, e.g.

```
>> range(2012, 2014)
.. [2012, 2013]
```